# Unexplained Google Analytics hits - 24 a day from 12 US cities

Tags: google-analytics, bots

For a little under a week now we have seen some annoying bot-traffic on on our site. What happens is that every day we get around 24 hits from a total of 12 US cities. That's 288 hits and since we are a new and still pretty low traffic site, this messes up our analytics.

The 12 cities are always the same and they are: Gilbert, Canon City, Clarksville, New York, Madison, Weston, Morgan City, Myrtle Beach, Dallas, Reston, Townshend, Dunwoody.

All hits are direct to the home page and 100% bounce with a 0:00 duration.

We had a Pingdom automated test set up for a few hours last week, so we thought this could be it. But I've just spoken with support, and they assure me it isn't. There are no active tests running on our URL.

So what the heck is it? Can anybody recognize this?

thanks ...

Comment: does the name of the service provider for any of these hits provide any clue?

Comment: @tony Yes, thanks, it does. I have tracked this down to it probably all coming from Gomez. Problem is, I have not asked Gomez to check my site, so someone else must have. The traffic is coming from these providers: "Gomez advisors", "Level 3 communications inc.", "Cerfnet", "Compuware corporation", "Gomez Advisors inc.", "Qwest communications company llc", "Sprint", "Ci - Gomez inc. sid-17189", "Gomez advisor" and "Mci communications services inc. d/b/a veriszon business". How can I filter all these without also filtering healthy traffic?

Comment: In the Admin page, select a profile, then select Filters. Then you can create complex custom filters. 
Another thing to try is to create a new custom segment and filter by User Agent or duration.

Comment: Yes, I have successfully created a custom segment using the AND operator. But I would prefer to completely filter out this bot traffic, and in Admin > Profile > Filters I can't use the AND operator. So what do I do? To make a working filter I need to filter by the ISP AND by duration/city/bounce rate or some other second variable. Thanks ...

Comment: I had a similar issue. I wound up trying to block them with robots.txt (didn't work - ignored it). So eventually I just blocked the traffic on the web server level by denying requests with Gomez in the UA header. I don't think there's a great way to do this in GA, since you can't get the raw UA string in Analytics.